# VBA to add hyperlink function to each cell in a column

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Hello and thank you in advance for your help. Currently I created the Macro below that updates the range with a hyperlink function. This works great. 
However, the issue is that this data gets refreshed via a datasource. Once refreshed there are blanks in Column A. Is there a way to execute this when a refreshed datasource occurs?

```
Sub InsertHyperlinkFormulaInCell()

ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Query").Range("A2:A20000").Formula = 
"=HYPERLINK(CONCAT(x2,B2),W2)"

End Sub
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

[image]

Answer (score 1):

you need to loop through the rows to change the hyperlink in every row otherwise you're just changing row 1.
If you want to keep the Excel reference in the sheet you can just exchange the row number in a for loop (or in this case while loop) which is sometimes nice to have but it makes for clunky code in the concatenation process.

```
Sub InsertHyperlinkFormulaInCell()

    'starting with row 2 since row 1 is title row
    currentRow = 2

    ' cells allows to call columns by number instead of letters (so A becomes 1, B:2 etc.)
    While Cells(currentRow, 2) <> "" 'check whether Column B is empty, stop if it is
        'This is your active line, just replaced the row number 1 with the variable currentRow
        'which loops through the sheet until it encounters and empty cell in column B
        ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells(currentRow, 1) = "=HYPERLINK(CONCAT(B" & currentRow & ",C" & currentRow & "),D" & currentRow & ")"
        currentRow = currentRow + 1
    Wend

End Sub
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Actually, the hyperlink line can just be changed to =HYPERLINK(CONCAT(RC[1],RC[2]),RC[3]). If you prefer the letter column style excel will automatically change it. However, in the R1C1 style (columns are numbered) the formula is the same for every row so that makes it a lot less clunky.

Comment: I must have updated my script right when you posted this. However, yours is so much cleaner! Thank you!

Comment: Is there a way to execute this after a refresh All is clicked/completed on a datasource? That was also part of my edit/update. Thanks again!

Comment: Not sure how your update occurs but usually the way to add a function that executes on change is to add the sub "Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target as Range)" to you worksheet-> Go to your VB window, double click on your "Query" worksheet and select worksheet and selectionChange, that should create it. Paste or call your code from here and it should trigger whenever there's a change in the worksheet.

Comment: If you want to limit the range that triggers your code insert an if statement on the target variable. For example if you want it to only run if there's a change in column A: if Target.column = 1 then InsertHyperlinkFormulaInCell().

Comment: I tried this but it only works when a change is manually changed Maybe i didn't execute it properly. However, the following seems to work for my scenario. Thanks for the help!                         
   ActiveWorkbook.Connections("query1").OLEDBConnection.BackgroundQuery = False
    ActiveWorkbook.Connections("query1").Refresh